# Почему не нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

**Когда я увижу статью( )опубликованной?**

Да, отглагольное прилагательное стоит после определяемого слова.Но запятую как-то не поставишь. Может, все дело в том, что слово "опубликованной" явлется частью составного именного сказуемого?

Comment: >>>слово "опубликованной" явлется частью составного именного сказуемого  
Это больше смахивает на предикатив. Да и падеж этот называется творительным предикатива.  

В моем ответе добавлена ссылка на статью, похоже - в тему, но я сам пока до конца её не прочитал.

Answer (score 1):

А хороший вопрос.
Здесь нет грамматики причастного оборота. 
Сравните: "Когда я видел её молодой и счатливой", "Когда я на почте служил ямщиком" и т.д.

Никакие зависимые слова тут не изменят ситуации. **Когда я увижу вашу статью опубликованной в журнале?**
Статья в форме винительного падежа, опубликованной - в творительном, ни о каком причастном обороте речь идти не может. Обычное дополнение в роли творительного предикативного.

сататья на тему (не прочитанная пока): [www.vestnik-mgou.ru/mag/2009/rusfil/2/st4.pdf](http://www.vestnik-mgou.ru/mag/2009/rusfil/2/st4.pdf)

А нет, это не совсем то. Жаль. Но все равно интересно. Пусть пока повисит для общего развития. 
Я найду литературу попозже.

Comment: Статья не о том. Я вчера уже комментировала один из ответов на этот вопрос. Причастие в данном предложении никак не может быть частью составного именного сказуемого, поскольку никакого отношения к субъекту не имеет: увижу я, а опубликованной будет статья. Запятая, конечно, не нужна. Тоже ищу объяснение. Вопрос с заковыкой.

Comment: Вы комментировали мой ответ, и именно благодаря Вам мне пришлось отнестись к вопросу гораздо серьёзнее, он того явно заслуживает. Ответ пришлось сформулировать уже на другом уровне. Благодарю Вас.

Comment: >>> поскольку никакого отношения к субъекту не имеет: увижу я, а опубликованной будет статья

Помнится, подобный синтаксис носит название **ко-предикативных** (или как-то так)отношений. Хотя могу и путать детали, но сама по себе такая ситуация не есть что-то из ряда вон выходящее.

Answer (score 1):

Это достаточно сложный спорный вопрос, касающийся составного именного сказуемого, где именная часть выражена причастием.  Или вопрос  о так называемом  "предикативном определении". Предикативное определение  может иметь имеет двойную зависимость. С одной стороны, от глагола в сказуемом "увижу КАКОЙ? опубликованной", с другой стороны, от объекта "увижу статью КАКОЙ? опубликованной". Это так называемый "объектный предикативный определитель". Ср.: ***Я оставил письмо нераспечатанным.*** ***Почему вы выписали пациента недолеченным?*** ***"Оставим этот вопрос нерешённым"***. (Примеры мои)
Проблема заключается в том, что в составном глагольном сказуемом и вспомогательный, и основной глагол характеризуют действия субъекта, а в составном именном сказуемом связка и именная часть могут характеризовать признак как бы со стороны, не от субъекта. ***Окна были открыты.***  
Глагол -связка и именная часть могут быть относительно свободными. 
В Вашем примере (Когда я увижу статью опубликованной?) как раз такой сложный случай. Слово "опубликованной" относится и к глаголу "увижу", характеризующему действия субъекта Я, и к объекту "статью". Ср.:***Сосед по площадке оставил почему-то  дверь приоткрытой.***  Глагол-связка "оставил"относится к субъекту, а именная часть "приоткрытой"- к объекту. Запятая потому и не ставится, что речь идёт всё-таки о предикативной конструкции.  Вот такие соображения.

P.S. Чтобы ничего не искать:
**Предикативное определение**. Определение, находящееся в атрибутивно-предикативных отношениях с подлежащим или прямым дополнением. *Дети воспитанные так не поступают* (дети какие? — воспитанные; при каком условии так не поступают?— если они воспитаны). *Анисья не нарядная сидит за станом* (Л. Толстой) (какая Анисья? в к а-ком виде сиди т?).**Я ВИЖУ СВОЮ ДОЧЬ УЛЫБАЮЩЕЙСЯ** ***(связь с дополнением-существительным, выражающаяся в согласовании в роде и числе, и связь со сказуемым: вижу к а к о и?).*** См. атрибутивно-предикативный, а также обстоятельственное определение.(http://www.classes.ru/grammar/114.Rosental/15-p-2/html/unnamed_39.html)

Comment: Так все-таки это не часть именного сказуемого! Спасибо за ссылку!

Comment: Как раз таки часть. Это (повторюсь)вопрос о составном именном сказуемом. Правда, вызывающий пока споры.

Comment: У меня ссылка почему-то не открывается. Екатерина, не могли бы Вы написать название книги. Вижу по ссылке, что Розенталь.

Comment: Сотрите последнюю закрывающую скобку. Это Словарь лингвистических терминов Розенталя.

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Comment: >>>Это (повторюсь)вопрос о составном именном сказуемом. 

Боюсь, что это уже вопрос грамматической школы, как трактовать, а еще точнее - как формализовывать грамматику. Ну пусть будет по Розенталю, не возражаю. Что это нам дает для понимания ситуации в целом?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, предложение "Когда я увижу статью опубликованной?" простое, с одним предикативным центром, а слово "опубликованной" - несогласованное определение. Неполное согласование - согласование, при котором использованы не все возможные морфологические средства уподобления форм зависимого слова формам господствующего слова.  Ср.: *Вижу мальчика улыбающимся* (согласование определения *улыбающимся* с определяемым существительным *мальчика* в роде и числе, но не в падеже; ср. устаревшую конструкцию "*вижу мальчика улыбающегося*" — с полным согласованием). (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1527/согласование). 
Все характеристики данного предложения (простое, ничем не осложненное) указывают на то, что никаких запятых здесь быть не должно.

Comment: Просто и убедительно!

Comment: olsa, а если вернуться к зависимым словам?
*Когда я увижу статью опубликованной в вашем журнале?*

Что тут такое? Неужели грамматика поменялась?
И потом, то факт, что это несогласованное определение (не вдаваясь пока в вопрос, так ли это в нашем случае) не снимает вопрос о трактовке как части именного сказуемого.

Comment: Надеюсь, вы согласитесь, что слово "опубликованной" характеризует статью, а не "Я"? Теперь разберемся, может ли слово, не характеризующее субъект, быть именной частью сказуемого? Определение сказуемого гласит: "Сказуемое - главный член предложения, характеризующий ПОДЛЕЖАЩЕЕ по действию или признаку в модальном и временном аспектах и отвечающее на вопросы ЧТО ДЕЛАЕТ? КАКОВ ПРЕДМЕТ? ЧТО ТАКОЕ ПРЕДМЕТ? ЧТО ПРОИСХОДИТ С ПРЕДМЕТОМ?..." (Большой лингв.словарь Стариченка). Все согласны, что подлежащее - "Я". Я что сделаю? увижу. Все! Вот наша основа. Все остальное - второстепенные члены предложения

Comment: Я не отрицаю, что "опубликованной" связано как и объектом, так и с  предикатом, но это не та связь, которая позволила бы назвать причастие именной частью сказуемого. Определение (несогласованное, предикативное и др.) все равно не главный, а второстепенный член предложения. Что касается зависимых от причастия слов, то, думаю, объяснение непостановки запятой можно найти. Только надо поискать.

Comment: Не обособляются распространенные определения, стоящие после определяемого существительного, если последнее не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении. Примеры: "Если вы человек себя уважающий...",  "Все они оказались учениками хорошо подготовленными" и др. Источник:Розенталь. Справочник по орфографии и пунктуации. 

Так и в данном предложении. Не в том дело, когда он увидит статью (он её видел и,возможно, сам и писал), а важно, когда ее опубликуют.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы у причастия были зависимые слова (опубликованной где?и т.п.), тогда, конечно, нужна была запятая при причастном обороте после определяемого слова. Падеж я не учитывала:((

Comment: Хоть десять зависымых. Нет здесь запятой.

Comment: Инна, я сейчас крепко задумался, похоже тут будет о чем поговорить всем нам.   

Запятая не нужна стопроцентно, а вот если обобщать на разные случаи... Примеры надо будет придумать. 
Пока тайм-аут беру, некогда, потом, наверное, отдельную тему открою.

Answer (score 0):

Русский язык подвижный, так что прилагательное может стоять как перед существительным, так и после него. Запятая не ставится.

Answer (score -1):

К сведению лиц, которые обсуждают вопрос ernest00

"В английском языке причастия появились раньше сложных глагольных форм. Предложение типа: I have written a letter, оформленное в современном языке перфектом, исторически произошло от предложений типа: I have a letter written, в котором written (причастие) входило не в состав сказуемого, а являлось определением слова letter (буквально: *я имею письмо написанным*)." (процитировано по В.Р. Гундризер, А.С. Ланда "Учебник английского языка").

Comment: Позвольте полюбопытствовать: а при чем здесь английский язык?

Comment: Предложение «I have a letter written.» состоит из подлежащего "I", сказуемого "have", дополнения "a letter"  и, наконец, определения "written"  к указанному дополнению.

В предложении «I have a letter written.» отсутствует запятая после дополнения "a letter" перед определением "written".

Comment: Как английский язык связан с нашим вопросом?

Comment: Что Вы называете "нашим вопросом"?

Comment: Это вопрос, на который мы здесь ищем ответ. :-)))   Ernest00 спрашивает: «Почему не нужна запятая в предложении "Когда я увижу статью( )опубликованной?"»

Comment: Я не размышлял над "связью" английского языка с вопросом Ernest00 «Почему не нужна запятая в предложении "Когда я увижу статью()опубликованной?"», на который Вы и вы ищете здесь ответ.